# group by using two collections in mongo

Tags: mongodb, join, group-by, average

```
I have two following mongodb collections:

fact:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab70427fc08b4855d3c4ea2"), 
    "game_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "time_id" : NumberInt(222), 
    "average_score" : NumberInt(8), 
    "count_editor_choice" : NumberInt(0)
}

game_dimension:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab703dcfc08b4855d3c0666"), 
    "game_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "title" : "#IDARB", 
    "genre" : "Party", 
    "platform" : "Xbox One"
}

I wish to find this:
 Which platform had the most editor choice=1?

For this, i am using the query as follows:
db['fact '].aggregate([

{ 
            "$match" : {
                "editors_choice" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }, 

{ "$lookup": {
    "localField": "game_id",
    "from": "game_dimension",
    "foreignField": "game_id",
    "as": "data"
} } ,

{$unwind: '$data'},
 {
   $group:
    { 
      _id: '$data.platform',
       "count(editors_choice)": 
      {
        $sum: 1
        }
      }
   },
   { 
            "$project" : {

                "platform" : "$data.platform", 
                "COUNT(editors_choice)" : "$count(editors_choice)"
            } }
])
```

-it displays 0  documents. I am naive at mongo, a little help with this query would clear a lot of my doubts (and explain too if possible would be a plus).

-i am struggling with doing group by and finding average of a value by group using 2  collections. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the `$match` stage you filter by the `editors_choice` field which I cannot see in the `fact` example document. Could you rephrase this: *Which platform had the most editor choice=1?* - it is unclear what you mean.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing out the error, actually it helped me get the solution..

Comment: FYI: if you found a solution you can also post that as an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, here it is:

The collections:

```
fact:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab70427fc08b4855d3c4ea2"), 
    "game_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "time_id" : NumberInt(222), 
    "average_score" : NumberInt(8), 
    "count_editor_choice" : NumberInt(0)
}

game_dimension:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab703dcfc08b4855d3c0666"), 
    "game_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "title" : "#IDARB", 
    "genre" : "Party", 
    "platform" : "Xbox One"
}
```

The correct code:

```
db['fact '].aggregate([

{ 
            "$match" : {
                "count_editor_choice" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }, 

{ "$lookup": {
    "localField": "game_id",
    "from": "game_dimension",
    "foreignField": "game_id",
    "as": "data"
} } ,

{$unwind: '$data'},
 {
   $group:
    { 
      _id: '$data.platform',
       "count(count_editor_choice)": 
      {
        $sum: 1
        }
      }
   },
   { 
            "$project" : {

                "platform" : "$data.platform", 
                "COUNT(count_editor_choice)" : "$count(count_editor_choice)"
            } }
])
```